# ace-window cursor to minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer, ace-window

How to configure `ace-window` to put the active cursor always into minibuffer when pressing a special key (like i.e. '`z`').

Reason is: I think it would be more convenient to always just press '`z`' for switching to minibuffer.

`ace-window`s wiki mentions `aw-dispatch-alist`, but I'm unable to use it for this problem.

Comment: normally the hotkey for the minibuffer is displayed, have you deliberately removed it?

Comment: do you know why it doesn't show with your config? it is invisible in your theme, you removed it ...? It seems that your problem is that it doesn't show.

Comment: you might like that way to switch windows: http://sachachua.com/blog/2015/01/emacs-microhabit-switching-windows-windmove-ace-window-ace-jump/?shareadraft=baba27863_54bd285449177

Comment: @Tyler yes I set `aw-minibuffer-flag` to true, because in the beginning I was experimenting with other tools. Nevertheless I'd like to have a constant key here.

Comment: @adl thanks for the comments, please see my comment to Tylers comment.

Answer (score 1):

The simple version is to first define a function which makes ace-window switch to the minibuffer if it's active

```lisp
(defun aw-switch-to-minibuffer ()
    (if (active-minibuffer-window)
        (aw-switch-to-window (active-minibuffer-window))
        (message "Minibuffer is not active")))
```

and then add it to the dispatch list:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'aw-dispatch-list '(?z aw-switch-to-minibuffer))
```

Comment: I'm using `windmove` instead of `ace-window` now, so I can't verify your solution.